# How to search between two Streams in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I have 2 Streams like coming in a method as shown below

```
public Stream<Transaction> getPendingTransaction(Stream<PendingTransaction> pendingTransactionStream,Stream<ProcessedTransaction> processedTransactionStream){ }
```

and I want to find all objects which are present in `pendingTransactionStream` which are  also present in `processedTransactionStream` based upon some criteria like

> if `transaction.getId()` is same for an Transaction object present in
>   `pendingTransactionStream` and `processedTransactionStreamthen` that
>   object is same and we can collect them in a list.

I tried doing like this but its giving error

```
processedTransactionStream
        .filter( (processedTransaction)->
        {
            pendingTransactionStream.anyMatch(s->s.getTransactionId().equals(processedTransaction.getTransactionId()) );
        } 
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't iterate `Stream`s more than once. So your current code doesn't work (you get an exception like `IllegalStateException: Stream already closed`. From the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> A stream should be **operated on** (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) **only once**.

A possible solution would be to convert the `pendingTransactionStream` into a map  where the key is the type of the `id` (I use string, because I don't know the keyType):

> Actually a `Set` would be better as you don't need the `PendingTransaction` for anything else, for an example have a look at [@Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194168/5515060)

```
Map<String, PendingTransaction> pendingTransactionMap = pendingTransactionStream
    .collect(PendingTransaction::getId, Function.identity());
```

And then `filter` your `processedTransactionStream`, by checking if the id is in the map:

```
List<ProcessedTransaction> processedTransactionList = processedTransactionStream
    .filter(p -> pendingTransactionMap.containsKey(p.getId()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can't consume the `pendingTransactionStream` `Stream` multiple times. You can transform it to a `List` (or even better, a `Set`) of transaction IDs to use in the `filter` method.

```
Set<String> pending = pendingTransactionStream.map(PendingTransaction::getTransactionId)
                                              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<ProcessedTransaction> processed = 
    processedTransactionStream.filter(pt -> pending.contains(pt.getTransactionId()))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```